# PHP Azure blob upload larger than allowed size

Tags: php, azure-blob-storage

I am using the following solution below from another answer.  However it will only send files of up to 64MB.  How do I send a large file with this method?  I could split the file in to pieces but then I can't reconstruct them once they are sent.

```
$accesskey = "qJXTMmw2Esal8/tXgfWk0RLwMNJ6OQKEt0E8EMZ8VhQrzGi5uqJqeKvi1l7iqnOddp7bdtai5rPpC6ynHttl1w==";$storageAccount = 'mystorage';
$filetoUpload = realpath('./image.jpg');

$containerName = '<yourblobcontainer>';
$blobName = 'image.jpg';

$destinationURL = "https://$storageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName";

function uploadBlob($filetoUpload, $storageAccount, $containerName, $blobName, $destinationURL, $accesskey) {
$currentDate = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", time());
$handle = fopen($filetoUpload, "r");
$fileLen = filesize($filetoUpload);

$headerResource = "x-ms-blob-cache-control:max-age=3600\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:$currentDate\nx-ms-version:2015-12-11";
$urlResource = "/$storageAccount/$containerName/$blobName";

$arraysign = array();
$arraysign[] = 'PUT';               /*HTTP Verb*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Encoding*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-Language*/  
$arraysign[] = $fileLen;            /*Content-Length (include value when zero)*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*Content-MD5*/  
$arraysign[] = 'image/png';         /*Content-Type*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*Date*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Modified-Since */  
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-None-Match*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*If-Unmodified-Since*/  
$arraysign[] = '';                  /*Range*/  
$arraysign[] = $headerResource;     /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
$arraysign[] = $urlResource;        /*CanonicalizedResource*/

$str2sign = implode("\n", $arraysign);

$sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($str2sign)), base64_decode($accesskey), true));  
$authHeader = "SharedKey $storageAccount:$sig";

$headers = [
    'Authorization: ' . $authHeader,
    'x-ms-blob-cache-control: max-age=3600',
    'x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob',
    'x-ms-date: ' . $currentDate,
    'x-ms-version: 2015-12-11',
    'Content-Type: image/png',
    'Content-Length: ' . $fileLen
];

$ch = curl_init($destinationURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $handle); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fileLen); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo ('Result<br/>');
print_r($result);

echo ('Error<br/>');
print_r(curl_error($ch));

curl_close($ch);
}

uploadBlob($filetoUpload, $storageAccount, $containerName, $blobName, $destinationURL, $accesskey);
```

Comment: Do you have any updates? Is it useful for you? if it is helpful for you, could you please accept it as an answer? It may help more people who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload large size file to Azure Blob Storage with PHP, you can use [Azure PHP storage SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php).

For example

```
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; 

use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\BlobRestProxy;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Exceptions\ServiceException;

use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\Block;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\CommitBlobBlocksOptions;

define('CHUNK_SIZE', 1024*1024);//Block Size = 1 MB
try {

    $connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=andyprivate;AccountKey=h4pP1fe76m8hdksFW3TvkO6hgw09Mjue7yJOnULPI/g2eU8LGJ+a6k6SrU6dUkOU77waZfU8CacyVMlTWAUA5A==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
   
    $blobRestProxy = BlobRestProxy::createBlobService($connectionString);
    $containerName = "upload";
    $blobName = "psd7003.xml";
    $fileName="d:/download/psd7003.xml";
    $content = fopen("d:/download/psd7003.xml", "rb");
    $index = 0;
    $continue = True;
    $counter = 1;
    $blockIds = array();
    while (!feof($content))
    {
        $blockId = str_pad($counter, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $block = new Block();
        $block -> setBlockId(base64_encode($blockId));
        $block -> setType("Uncommitted");
        array_push($blockIds, $block);
        echo $blockId . " | " . base64_encode($blockId) . " | " . count($blockIds);
        echo " \n ";
        echo " -----------------------------------------";
        $data=fread($content, CHUNK_SIZE);
        echo "Read " . strlen($data) . " of data from file";
        echo " \n ";
        echo " -----------------------------------------";
        echo " \n ";
        echo " -----------------------------------------";
        echo "Uploading block : " . $blockId + " into blob storage. Please wait.";
        echo " -----------------------------------------";
        echo " \n ";
        $blobRestProxy -> createBlobBlock($containerName, $blobName, base64_encode($blockId), $data);
        echo "Uploaded block: " . $blockId . " into blob storage. Please wait";
        echo " \n ";
        echo " -----------------------------------------";
        echo " \n ";
        $counter = $counter + 1;
    }
    fclose($content); 
    echo "Now committing block list. Please wait.";
    echo " -----------------------------------------";
    echo " \n ";
    echo "hello";
    $options = new CommitBlobBlocksOptions();
    $option -> setContentType(mime_content_type($fileName));
    $blobRestProxy -> commitBlobBlocks($containerName, $blobName, $blockIds,$options);
    echo " -----------------------------------------";
    echo " \n ";
    echo "Blob created successfully.";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}
?>
```

Besides, if you want to implement it with rest API, please refer to the following steps

#### 1. Read the whole file to bytes, and divide the file into smaller pieces in your code.

- Maybe 8 MB for each pieces.

#### 2. Upload each piece with [Put Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) API.

- In each request, it contains a blockid.

#### 3. Make up the blob with [Put Block List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list) API.

- In this request, you need to put all the blockid in the body in ordered.